# fluentd input in_udp and output it to tcp

Tags: tcp, udp, logstash, fluentd

I have an udp input in fluentd :

```
<source> # mylog
  @type udp
  port 41234
  tag json
  <parse>
    @type none
  </parse>
</source>
```

I'd like to pass it through a tcp ouput,because I go through haproxys and then in a logstash input. Historic reason.

I got it worked with @type forward for output, So I assume it forward udp, according to the doc.
But then in logstash side I got some extra weird characters around the payload. logstash conf :

```
input {
  tcp {
    host => "127.0.0.1"
    port => 41234
    codec => "json"
  }
}
```

How would you do that ? Is that even possible?